# Dividing students to three Buses

Tags: probability, combinatorics

5 friends want to join a school trip. Students attending the trip are shared randomly on 3 buses, A, B and C.

1. What is the probability that the all the 5 friends are on bus A?
2. What is the probability that the all the 5 friends are **on any one** of the buses?
3. What is the probability that 3 of the 5 friends are **on any one** of the buses?

I tried solving but in terms of probability, we should divide by the total number of ways, but I couldn't get that since there is no total number of students to choose from neither is there a number of students in each bus/group.

Any idea?

Comment: There are $3$ buses, so the probability a student is on bus A (or B or C) is $1/3$

Comment: If you want to count total number of ways, given appropriate assumptions for the problem (*capacity of buses is sufficiently large, bus assignments for our people are independently chosen*), you can describe the number of different possibilities as being $3^5$.  There are $3$ choices for which bus person 1 is on, $3$ choices for the bus that person 2 is on, etc... on to the fifth person, and multiplying these together gives the count of $3^5$. That being said, restricting yourself to only solving with counting methods can make things unnecessarily difficult in some problems.

Comment: The third problem requires  a small clarification : do you want exactly three people on that bus in which three people are there, or can there be more people?(Would that count?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying assumption is that you can fit as many (or few) of the five friends on any of the buses, and the rest of the students (which you don't care about for the purposes of this problem) will adjust to accommodate.

Each of the five friends can be on any of the buses, so the total number of possibilities is $3^5$. Then it's a matter of counting the number of possibilities for each case.

1. They're all on Bus A, so there's only one choice.
2. Choose the bus they're all on. There are three buses, so therefore three choices.
3. Pick the three friends on the same bus $(_5C_3)$ and pick the bus $(3)$. Then pick the buses that the other two friends are on $(2^2)$.

If #3 involves *at least* three on the same bus, then repeat for four friends on the same bus, and then five (which you've already done).

Expanding on my answer to number 3: We need to multiply those three numbers together to get all of the possibilities. We can choose the three friends on the same bus, *but* there are three choices for which bus any particular three friends are on. Once we have that, there are $2^2=4$ choices for where the two left-out friends go, given any particular group of three friends *and* any particular bus.

By the time we're done, the probability is $120/243$, or nearly one-half.

Comment: I cannot understand the answer.
Correct me if I'm wrong:
1) 1/3^5


2) 3/3^5

3) 5C3 = 10 so 10/3^5

Comment: Multiply for 3): $10 \cdot 3 \cdot 4/3^5$

Comment: Can you please expand on number 3? Why do we multiply by 3 and then 4? The third question doesn't say anything about the other 2 students

Comment: I added more explanation to my answer.